# Frequency shift of Duffing oscillator with Boltzmann-distributed amplitude

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I have two coupled oscillators, namely a particle in an ion trap and an RLC circuit. The particle oscillates in this ion trap and induces charges in the RLC circuit, in turn the RLC circuit's voltage oscillates and drives the particle. Energy is dissipated via the resistor in the RLC circuit and at the same time added due to thermal noise.

The trap potential has a small nonlinear perturbation.
The corresponding differential equations for the particle and circuit respectively are:

\begin{align}
\ddot x + C_2 x + C_4 x^3 &= \kappa L I  \\
\ddot I + \frac{1}{RC} \dot I + \frac{1}{LC} I &= \frac{1}{LC} I_{noise} + \frac{\kappa}{LC} \dot x
\end{align}

Where $x$ is the displacement of the ion in the potential and $I$ is the current through the coil of the RLC circuit (one could also choose the current through the resistor or capacitor, it doesn't matter). $R$ is small enough that the eigenfrequency of the RLC circuit is the one of the undamped LC circuit. Additionally I am interested in the on-resonance case, namely that the undisturbed particle and circuit frequencies are the same: $ \omega_{0, circuit}^2 = \frac{1}{LC} = C_2 = \omega_{0,ion}^2$. The noise is white random noise, i.e. its autocorrelation time is a Dirac-distribution but it has a certain standard deviation $\sigma(I_{noise(t)}) > 0$.

The small nonlinearity in the trapping potential causes the eigenfrequency of the particle to shift slighlty. I see numerically that this is a function of $\kappa$. My question is: How does one calculate the frequency shift as a function of $\kappa$?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to average frequency over $x_0$? Or do you want to consider fluctuations near the minimum of the potential?

Comment: Do the coefficients have specific signs? In other words: is it a potential with one globally stable minimum ($\alpha > 0,\beta>0$), two minima ($alpha<0,\beta>0$) or one locally stable minimum ($\alpha>0,\beta<0$)?

Comment: @Vadim I want to calculate the frequency shift depending on how fast $x_0$ changes. I have done numerical calculations where I see that depending on how fast I let my oscillator sample the Boltzmann distribution, the frequency $\omega$ changes

Comment: @Vadim Yes, the coefficients have signs, I can even tell you the rough values: $\alpha \approx 1.5\cdot10^{13}$ with $\alpha \approx \omega^2$ (small frequency shifts) and $x_0 \approx 10^{-5}$ and $\beta \approx 10^{16}$

Comment: Could you provide more details, specifically about how you arrive at the frequency response, and what is $x_0$? The wiki article that you linked suggests finding the amplitude ($x_0$?) given known frequency ($\omega$), but your question seems to suggest the opposite problem.

Comment: @Vadim well the frequency response is simply the one from wikipedia with $\gamma = 0$ and $\delta = 0$. Yes, $x_0$ is the amplitude of the oscillator.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that you find $x_0$ from your second equation - where does the Boltzmann distribution come into the picture?

Comment: see my comment regarding the physics below.

Comment: Thanks you, your edit does clarify the things. So what you are really looking for is the frequency shift of the circuit, rather than the behavior of the oscillator - unlike in the pure  Duffing problem, where oscillator is driven by a constant frequency term.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the frequency shift of the particle due to the non-linear term

Comment: The frequency in the Duffing formula that you are trying to use is the external driving frequency (assuming a constant frequency force), not the frequency of the oscillator.

Comment: Yes, I have realized this thanks to your answer. I will just delete the original part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principled way of introducing the temperature is by adding the damping and noise terms, related via the Einstein relation, so that the stationary distribution is the Boltzmann distribution. I.e., we start with
$$
\ddot{x} + \delta \dot{x} + \alpha x + \beta x^3 = \xi(t),
$$
where
$$
\langle \xi(t)\rangle = 0,\\
\langle \xi(t)\xi(t')\rangle = D\delta(t-t'),
$$
formulate the equivalent Fokker-Planck equation, and its equilibrium solution will be a Boltzmann one, with the temperature expressed in terms of $D$ and $\delta$. This damping and driving thus may be not exactly the same as you already have implicitly in your system - they are a way to drive the system to the Boltzmann distribution. One could then add the driving terms to the Fokker-Planck equation, $\sim\cos(\omega t)$ to study the resulting response characteristic.

As a shortcut around it one could simply solve the equation for frequency and average the results over the Boltzmann distribution with the potential in the equation:
$$
-\partial_x V(x) = -\alpha x -\beta x^3
$$

**Update**
In response to the expanded question: the straighforward approach would be to write a joint Fokker-Plank equation for the particle and the circuit,
$$
\partial_t P(x, \dot{x}, I, \dot{I},t) = ...
$$
and study its behavior. In particular, if $C_2$ and $C_4$ are both positive, the solution is globally stable and one can write the equilibrium Boltzmann-like solution of the FPE. Note that this is not a true Boltzmann distribution, since one cannot define a potential energy, as the coupling term contains time derivative $\dot{x}$.

I could suggest as a rough estimate to calculate the equilibrium state of the non-linear system in absence of noise, by first writing it as a system of the four first order equations in new variables $y=\dot{x},J=\dot{I}$:
$$
\dot{x} = y,\\
\dot{y} = -C_2 x - C_4 x^3 + \kappa L I,\\
\dot{I} = J,\\
\dot{J} = -\frac{J}{RC} - \frac{I}{LC} + \frac{\kappa y}{LC}.
$$
One can then perform the standard non-linear analysis by finding the equilibrium solutions of this system, linearizing it around this solution, finding the eigenfrequencies near this equilibrium, and, finally, writing the Boltzmann-like distribution near the equilibrium.

Comment: The driving doesn't need to be exactly the same. The closest approximation would probably be $\xi(t) = p A_0 \cos(\omega t)$ where $p$ follows some random distribution and is newly rolled every autocorrelation time.

Comment: There is some confusion here: $\xi(t)$ is a Gaussian white noise, not the deterministic driving force. If you want both the noise and the periodic force, you need to write:
$f(t) = \xi(t) + pA_0\cos(\omega t)$

Comment: Well that's not really the case for my system. Maybe the actual physics helps here: I have a parallel RLC circuit which drives a particle in an ion trap. The random thermal noise of the resistor charges up the RLC circuit and the particle is excited by this oscillation. The ion in turn induces currents in this RLC circuit. If it were not for the thermal noise, the ion and RLC circuit would oscillate in phase. However, due to the thermal noise the amplitude and phase of the RLC-oscillation is modulated randomly, which is what I meant by implicit damping and driving.

Comment: It looks like you are confusing *noise* with *oscillations*...

Comment: I don't think so. The thermal noise is white, but the RLC-circuit is resonantly driven by the noise component at the RLC-circuit's eigenfrequency.

Comment: It might be not white noise, but it is definitely not $\cos(\omega t)$. I suggest that you edit your question and give more detailed description of the problem, perhaps even with a circuit diagram.

Comment: I don't think the RLC circuit matters, it can be modelled fairly well as a heat bath. The question for me is: How does the particle eigenfrequency change as a function of the coupling strength to the heat bath? As measure for the coupling strength I have used the autocorrelation time of the particle's energy.

Comment: I don't think that I or anybody else can tell you more without clarifying the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question, I hope things are clear now.

Comment: I have expanded the answer, proposing a way to deal with this system. However, this requires some work with pen and paper. This problem is not complicated, but it does require time investment.